# Meaning of '...some people recover from severe pain while others have long-term pain.'

Tags: meaning, comparison

I feel in a sense that it is a comparison, but 'severe pain' is not 'long-term pain' and accordingly the end of the sentence is extra. So I find this as a strange comparison. Could you clarify what's the point to end the sentence with - 'while others have long-term pain'.

> The NIH (National Institutes of Health) is interested in discovering
>   the biological markers that let **some people recover from severe pain
>   while others have long-term pain**.

US Health Agency Wants to Measure Pain
https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/us-health-agency-wants-to-measure-pain/4739047.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intended meaning is fairly clear: the contrast is not between *severe* and *long-term* pain but between the people who eventually recover from severe pain and those who continue to suffer severe pain over a long term.

The sentence is carelessly constructed.

- *Severe* modifying the second *pain* is deleted but implied, which is marginally acceptable.
- *Have long-term pain* is an awkward use of medical shorthand. *Long-term* (or 'chronic') pain is distinguished from *short-term* (or 'acute') pain; but in this context, where *pain* is coupled with the verb *have*, *long-term* is misplaced: the sentence should be recast so *long-term* modifies *have* rather than *pain*.